# Azure AD B2C password change and Blazor WASM

Tags: blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I setup a custom policy for password change using the following guide:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

But how do I call this policy from my Blazor Wasm app and which url with return url do I need to setup? When I run the costom policy and let it call the default return url nothing happens and my blazor wasm app stays in the "Logging in" state so probably on the Wasm side I also correctly need to handle the return.

I can't find any examples for change password in combination with Blazor WASM. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Cross possed on github: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42479

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you to please **follow the below github link** which describes on the process of integrating a Blazor WASM application with Azure AD B2C. In this, it describes that you will have to **define and create an app registration for Blazor WASM app in Azure AD B2C in which you will have to configure the redirect URI that will be used by the Blazor application during login and logout requests**.

***https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-blazor-wasm/blob/main/WebApp-OIDC/B2C/README.md#register-the-web-app-webapp-blazor-wasm***

According to the above link, you will have to **setup the following URL as redirect URI and below that as logout URI**: -

***Login Redirect URI: - https://localhost:44314/authentication/login-callback***

***Logout Redirect URI: - https://localhost:44314/signout-oidc***

•   Also, to **include the password change custom policy in your Blazor WASM application through Azure AD B2C, you will have to download the B2C custom policy starter pack** from the below link and modify the ***‘TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml’ policy file accordingly as said in the ‘Password Change’ documentation as described***.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack

After which, you will have to **upload the modified custom policy files in the ‘Identity Experience Framework’ custom policies section and execute the policy by selecting it in the list of policies that are uploaded and selecting the appropriate created Blazor WASM app in the Azure AD B2C app registration**. Have attached a snapshot below of the options to be selected for using the custom policies in Azure AD B2C: -

[image: Blazor WASM B2C Userflow]

In this way, you can call this policy using the Blazor WASM app in Azure AD B2C.

Comment: I saw this one, bute you actually can't call another policy outside the default signin-signup policy. For that you will need to replace MSAL authenticationservice and make a custom one as discussed in the github post. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42479

Comment: Unfortunately the default msal.js clientprovider is wrapped and unaccessable from javascript so you really need to replace the default one and that is giving me a huge headache, becuase building the custom AuthenticationService with Microsoft.AspNetCore.ClientAssets is clashing with my other Typescript definitions. I will probably have to wait untill https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38122 is included in .Net7